Android periodic task in background
Hi i need to run a periodic task to connect with the server every 4 min.
the task needs to run even if the device or app are closed,
is it possible in android ?
does workermanager ensure that the task will run every 4 min?

By "device is closed" I assume you mean the screen is off.  If so, there's no way to assure that unless you get your app whitelisted from power management.  That needs to be done by the user, there is no way to do it programatically.  Unless you do that, Doze mode will prevent you from running except once in a 15 minute window.
(Please note that some OEMs may be even more restrictive than stock android.  On those devices, even whitelisting from power management may not work).
I really suggest you tell us what you want to do every 4 minutes, we may be able to suggest a better way to accomplish that.
